# Удаление из вектора всех карт согласно значению параметра (iterator, vector::erase, и std::remove)

Tags: stl, c++

Задача следующего рода.
**Дано:**
Вектор из карт, общим числом 700 элементов.
**Что выполнить:**  
Удалить из вектора все карты, для которых строковый параметр price содержит "0.00" либо же "#ЗНАЧЕН!"

**Как я реализовал это**:

```
for (it = results_v.begin(); it != results_v.end(); it++) {
    if ((*it)["price"].find("0.00") != std::string::npos ||
        (*it)["price"].find("#ЗНАЧЕН") != std::string::npos)
    {
        end_of_range = std::remove(results_v.begin(), end_of_range, *it);
    }    
}

results_v.erase(end_of_range, results_v.end());
```

Проблема в том, что алгоритм работает совершенно не так, как я того ожидаю. Я ожидаю, что:

1. Раз я вызываю remove с итератором на текущий элемент в качестве начала и итератором end of range, который указывает на верхнюю границу "хорошего" массива, то remove должен вытолкнуть "плохой" элемент за end of range и вернуть итератор на верхнюю границу "хорошего" массива.
2. После каждой новой итерации "плохой" элемент будет выталкиваться их "хорошего" массива в "плохой" массив, а итератор end of range будет постепенно смещаться в сторону младших номеров.
3. Наконец, после цикла, что выталкивает все "плохие" элементы за границу end of range, мы будем иметь end of range, указывающий на начало "плохих" элементов.
4. После вызова vector::erase() в векторе остается 535 элементов, вместо ожидаемых 369.

Дополнено:
Почему, кстати, возникают проблемы при выполнении такого кода? Вроде ведь все валидно?

```
std::vector<std::string> str_v;                 
str_v.push_back("apple");
str_v.push_back("breed");
str_v.push_back("omega");
str_v.push_back("creschendo");
str_v.push_back("omega");
str_v.push_back("diamond");
str_v.push_back("omega");
str_v.push_back("greed");
std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator end_of_range;
for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator i = str_v.begin(); i!=str_v.end(); i++)
{
if(*i=="omega")
{
        str_v.erase(i);
}
}
```

Comment: Навскидку - вы удаляете элементы из `std::vector` во время итерации по нему. Это допустимо, но для того, чтобы все работало за 1 проход, нужно присваивать результат `std::remove` текущему итератору.

Comment: Почему? Ведь std::remove() возвращает итератор на начало "плохой" части массива. Получается следующий поиск будет с этого элемента?

Comment: Почему, в конце концов нельзя в цикле вызывать vector::erase()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Потому что ваш цикл происходит с помощью итераторов. Если вы удаляете какой-либо объект, то соответствующий итератор становится невалидным и нужно его "перескочить". Именно для этого `std::vector<T>::erase` возвращает следующий валидный итератор.
- Для этих целей есть удобный паттерн использования:

  ```
  if (shouldErase(it))
      it = collection.erase(it);
  else
      ++it;
  ```
- Еще лучше, если это возможно, использовать `std::remove_if` с правильным предикатом.

Comment: Класс, надо было только начать свой ответ со слов:

    Еще лучше, если это возможно, использовать std::remove_if с правильным предикатом.

А так верно, что геморройно будет обновлять итераторы каждый раз =)

Comment: @Asen Не всегда можно придумать удобный предикат, поэтому про `erase`  не стоит забывать :)

Answer (score 2):

```
results_v.erase(std::remove_if(results_v.begin(), results_v.end(),
  [](const item& x) -> bool { 
    return x["price"].find("0.00") != std::string::npos ||
           x["price"].find("#ЗНАЧЕН") != std::string::npos;
  }), 
  results_v.end());
```